# HTML 5 Datalist - How to autoselect if only one option is available

Tags: html, datalist

User types into the input box with datalist attached, one option is displayed that they can click on to select. How can I auto select that single option?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so `datalist` is an HTML5 element that allows for a native *autocomplete* feature on most modern browsers. That being said it does not provide the ability to set a default or selected option. Additionally it does not have `events` available so you need to do it using standard events on your elements.

**Example**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var datalist = $('#someCountries');
    var opts = datalist.find('option');

    console.log(opts.val());
    console.log(opts.length);

    function checkOpts() {
        if (opts.length === 1) {
            $('#country').val(opts.val());
        }
    }

    $('#country').on('focusin', checkOpts);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="country" list="someCountries" />
<datalist id="someCountries">
    <option label="United Stated" value="USA"></option>
</datalist>
```

You will probably need to modify the `focusin` event to something more appropriate for your situation, but this should get you on your way.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. Let's say there are 20 options in that list. You start typing until it filters down to just one. Is there a way to check the current state of the datalist as it's being filtered? In the countries example: if I add more countries and type, the jquery function only sees the original list and not what it has filtered down to. Would it be easier if I looked at using jquery autocomplete instead of html5 datalist?

Comment: If that is an option then yes, I would definitely recommend jQuery auto complete over datalist